# WPF override method after event triggered

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, overriding

I have a method that I want to override.
Right now, I placed the override directly in the code-behind.

This is part of the code-behind (but that's all you need).

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    ...
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
}

protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    ...
}
```

I want to apply the `OnSelectionChanged()` override after the `OnApplyTemplate()` done.
Is it possible? if it is, I would appreciate your help/explanation on how to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: WPF is a complex framework not suitable for the unexperienced. You seem to misunderstand the basics of OOP. I suggest you practice the basics of C# / OOP with some console applications or something before trying to dive into WPF. BTW, you only override `OnApplyTemplate()` and such when you are creating a CUSTOM control. You really need to know what you're doing here and make sure you're on the right track. Please provide some context information about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I assume your control has not been displayed yet but you are receiving SelectionChanged event, right? Is that that the reason why you want SelectionChanged to be after OnApplyTemplate?
That is by design. SelectedItems is just a property and nothing else and may be changed even when the control hasnt been displayed yet.
Though why you aint binding to SelectedItems property instead of listening to SelectionChanged event?

Comment: @HighCore this is CustomControl, I didnt mention but there's "custom-cotnrols" tag... I want to override OnSelectionChanged to trigger an event I made which do something. in that event I need to check if all the elements are not null or else I get en error in the designer. I want to bypass the isnull check by applying the override after the OnApplyTemplate - hopefully you understood what I want

Comment: @devhedgehog exactly, well I basically explained the problem in the comment above.

Comment: I understand. Well like I suggested use Binding and bind SelectedItem property to a property in your ViewModel :) When you select an item you will get notfied about that in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this simple trick.

```
private bool isEverythingLoaded;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    isEverythingLoaded = true;
    ...
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
}

protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(isEverythingLoaded)
    {
      base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
      ...
    }
}
```

Hehe. What you think of this?

SelectionChanged will be only fired when everything is loaded.

Comment: It works, no idea why I didnt think about it on my own... anyway, it feels hacky after your first suggestion to bind SelectedItem property but this is the easier solution and I will go with it.